# can we make a common & auto class (generics class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want a predefined class name which able to inherit css properties of immediate parent class/Id. let say

```
<div class="super">
   <input type="button" id="any_1" />
   <div class="sub">
      <input type="button" id="any_2" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to enclosed the `<input type="button" ... />` with a common class & this class should inherits the css properties of immediate parent node.

e.g. suppose `generic` is common class and i am re-writing the above example

```
<div class="super">
   <div class="generic"> /*This should inherits the css properties of super class*/
      <input type="button" id="any_1" />
   </div>
   <div class="sub">
      <div class="generic"> /*This should inherits the css properties of sub class*/
          <input type="button" id="any_2" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

is there any way to do that if the `generic` is  `selector`.

Comment: .super .generic{/*styles*/} and .sub .generic{/*styles*/}

Comment: The comment `/*This should inherits the css properties of sub class*/` is sort of ambigous and confusing as the class .sub is actually the parent class.

Comment: yes but please consider the selector as an object and generics is the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted two ways to return the class values of the input elements. **EDIT:** made a mistake, answer revised.

```
    //jquery
     $(function() {
        $('.generic').each(function() {
              var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
              $(this).addClass(parentClass);
        });
     });
```

Comment: Isn't .generic supposed to inherit from its parent? That is .super or .sub in the given example.

Comment: @Ivar Bonsaksen: Right, I missed that part

Comment: @user744587: Wow! I completely missed the question. answer is now edited.